# Testing many implementations of an interface (TDD)

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

What is the best practice when creating many implementations of an interface to ensure compliance with the interface's contract?

```
public interface IFoo {
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
    /// If <paramref name="baz"> is <c>null</c>.
    /// </exception>
    void Bar(Baz baz);
}
```

I was thinking about something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class IFooTestsBase {
    protected IFoo Foo;

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Bar_ThrowsException_WhenBazArgumentIsNull() {
        Foo.Bar(null);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class SpecialFooTests : IFooTestsBase {
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init() {
        // Provide instance of `SpecialFoo` for inherited tests.
        Foo = new SpecialFoo();
    }

    // TDD as normal from here...
}
```

Is this a valid TDD approach?

1. The test will initially not compile because the `SpecialFoo` class will not have been defined.
2. Create minimal `SpecialFoo` implementation that compiles but fails all tests.
3. The tests will then compile but not pass since the minimal `SpecialFoo` class will not meet the expectations of the interface.

Or should I be re-implementing each test one-by-one for each new implementation of `IFoo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly valid approach to make sure current (and future) implementors adhere to the (semantic) contract of an interface. The first time I heard about these kinds of tests was by J.B. Rainsberger, who calls them [contract tests](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2011/07/07/contract-tests-an-example/).

If you rely on mostly isolated testing (i.e. make heavy use of mocks), contract tests are a necessary alternative to writing integrated tests (that glue several real objects together instead). The isolated unit tests verify whether a unit works correctly in isolation, and the contract tests verify whether all assumptions you make about collaborators are guaranteed by their implementations. For more information about this style of isolated testing, you can always read up more on J.B's blog. A good place to get started is [integrated tests are a scam](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2010/10/16/integrated-tests-are-a-scam/).

J.B. is one of the most hardcore TDD'ers I know. He uses a TDD style that focuses on outside-in TDD working solely with isolated unit tests (i.e. makes heavy use of mocks). In his approach, you test-drive a SUT and create interfaces for each collaborator which you mock in your isolated unit tests for the SUT. When the SUT is designed, you go one level deeper and test-drive the implementation of a collaborator. In order to make sure these objects work together when glued together, he also suggests writing these contract tests as an alternative of writing an integrated test that wires the actual objects together: every assumption an object makes for a collaborator (e.g.: "all objects implementing this interface return null if they can't find a person with this id") can be reified in a contract test.